# Add nodes asynchronously to d3.hierarchy

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm writing a tree with D3 (v4) to show a particular type of data where the structure has a really high number of levels. Because of this, I've decided to load asynchronously every new level of data: when the user clicks a node I load async its children.

I achieved the desired result but I'm not sure it is the best way because I feel like I was rewriting the wheel. Can someone confirm my code or tell me a better way to fill my needs? I've found nothing over the internet about d3 and this asynchronism...

This is the simplified code:

*Tree initialization*

```
// Starting data
var data = {
    "name": "node1",
    "children": [{
        "name": "child1",
        "children": []
    }, { 
        "name": "child2",
        "children": []
    }]
};
// Tree creation
var root = d3.hierarchy(data);
```

*On click code*

```
function click(d) {
    loadChildrenFromServer(d, fooCallback);
}

function loadChildrenFromServer(d, callback) {
    //Simulating server call
    setTimeout(function () {
        //Mock async data
        var mockchildren = [{
            "name": "asyncChild1",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "asyncChild2",
            "children": []
        }];

        d.data.children = children;    //Updating data
        d.children = [];               //Initializing d3 node children

        children.forEach(function(dchild, index) {
            //Building 'Node' objects and adding them to children
            nodeData.children[index] = makeD3Node(dchild, d, index);
        });

        //Updating all height attributes
        updateHeightAttributeRecursively(d);

        callback();
    }, 100)
}

function makeD3Node(data, parent, index) {
    //I have to use d3.hierarchy because d3 Node constructor is not public
    var node = d3.hierarchy(data);
    node.parent = parent;
    node.depth = parent.depth + 1;
    node.children = null;
    node.data = data;
    node.height = 0;
    node.id = parent.id + '' + index;
    //updating my other attributes...
    return node;
}
```

I expected some kind of automatism to simplify this code (primarly to add nodes without worrying about the update of every attribute of the tree).

Ps: I've tried to recreate the entire tree adding new data to initial data and re-calling `d3.hierarchy(root)` but it brokes my animations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Ok, apparently no simpler way of doing this: https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/139